# Mod_rewrite to switch HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to use a Bluehost supplied SSL wildcard certificate to switch one subdomain to HTTPS.

The web root contains many subdomains, and I only want to affect the test. subdomain.

Going into the web root, I've written the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^test.mydomain.com        
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1
```

Yet hitting http://test.mydomain.com/admin/index.php does not redirect me to https://test.mydomain.com/admin/index.php.

Even cutting out the Condition of SERVER_NAME, it still doesn't work.

Is my rewrite rule bad?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the first place I was in the wrong .htaccess file.  I needed to go to the directory for my subdomain.

Then, simply switching it from HTTP to HTTP apparently causes some kind of redirect to www. behavior.

I had to

A) Preserve the existing rules that were not intended for test. 
B) Add the test. rules.

It added up to a lot.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test.example.com$  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test.example.com$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$     
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /test%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ test/admin/index.php [L]
```